# make Ubuntu server always ping to some ip

Tags: 16.04, server

i am newbie on ubuntu,now i have ubuntu server lts 16.4 and it connect to some devices, i have problem if i am not do ping always to our devices, our devices intranet connection running slowly and latency more than 1000 ms, i ever heard if there are way to make ubuntu server always ping to some ip , so please let me know how to do ?

Comment: How you connected via ssh?

Comment: to connect client i use snmp

Answer (score 3):

Try the following command on terminal:

```
ping 127.0.0.1 -i 5
```

Replace `127.0.0.1` with the ip of the device you want to ping and `5` with the time in seconds you want the ping to be repeated.

if it works, create a file with that, the output going to nothing:

```
ping 127.0.0.1 -i 5 > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Name the extension as `.sh` and make it executable - usually file managers have that option in the file properties.
Place the file anywhere you want, for example `/home/your-user-name/scripts/`

Now, set the file to run on startup. For that add a line with

```
/home/your-user-name/scripts/filename.sh
```

to /etc/rc.local. Make sure you put it before the line with "exit 0".
You will need admin rights for that. Try

> sudo -H gedit /etc/rc.local

Now it will start running on computer reboot and will run forever.

Comment: Remember that on linux file and directory names are case sensitive!

Comment: And also paths have forward slashes `/` and not backslashes ``\``

Comment: And also graphical apps should **never** be run with `sudo`, a small mistake can change permissions in the userspace. The `-H` parameter avoids that. (Há que ter cuidado com estas coisas, menino Pedro)

Comment: Thanks CelticWarrior for that tip. (Estamos sempre a aprender.)

Comment: how to check if its work or not? could i check the log?

Comment: Well, type on terminal `pgrep ping` . If it outputs a number  (PID number), ping is running; if it doesn't, ping isn't running.

Comment: pedro i just type pgrep ping , some time it outputs a number  and sometimes not, does it normal ?

Comment: i was try it , but it couldn't help me , i still got problem High latency for first i ping manually

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [Smokeping](http://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/).

Considering your question, you do not need to setup the web frontend - although you could want to.

Get it running:

```
sudo apt-get install smokeping
sudo nano /etc/smokeping/config.d/Targets
*** Targets ***
probe  = FPing
menu   = Top
title  = Network Latency Grapher
remark = MySmokePing

+ Publics
menu  = Publics
title = Public Latency

++ MyProbe1
menu  = MyProbe1
title = MyProbe1
host  = 8.8.8.8

++ MyProbe22
menu  = MyProbe2
title = MyProbe2
host  = 8.8.4.4
```

exit nano, reload configuration with `systemctl restart smokeping`.

Comment: i was trie this but i am still having problem